# Insert Value on recordset to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a problem that I have tried to work through and have hit a brick wall on and hoping that someone can help me out. I need to write from an unbound form to a SQL Server table but also pull the int primary key as part of the data for a Unique Number. Below is my code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnSCRID_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstSCR As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT [dbo_Master Shared Compliance Review].* FROM [dbo_Master Shared Compliance Review]"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstSCR = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)


If VerifyFields Then

    rstSCR.AddNew
    rstSCR![User ID] = Me.txtUSERID.Value
    rstSCR![Report Date] = Me.txtDate.Value
    rstSCR![Partner Name] = Me.txtPartner.Value
    rstSCR![Relationship] = Me.cboRelationship.Value
    rstSCR![Entity] = Me.cboEntity.Value
    rstSCR![Entry Number] = Me.txtEntryNum.Value
    rstSCR![ENTRY DATE] = Me.txtEntryDt.Value
    rstSCR![Vendor] = Me.txtVendor.Value
    rstSCR![PO Number] = Me.txtPO.Value
    rstSCR![UPC] = Me.txtUPC.Value
    rstSCR![VPN or Style Number] = Me.txtStyle.Value
    rstSCR![Item Description] = Me.txtItemDesc.Value
    rstSCR![Document Issues] = Me.cboDocIs.Value
    rstSCR![Valuation Issue] = Me.cboValIs.Value
    rstSCR![OGA Issues(Missing Forms)] = Me.cboOGAis.Value
    rstSCR![HTS Issue] = Me.cboHTSis.Value
    rstSCR![Comments] = Me.txtComm.Value
    rstSCR![Broker Email] = Me.chkBroker.Value
    rstSCR![PreAlert Shipment] = Me.chkPreAlert.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 1] = Me.txtHTS1.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 2] = Me.txtHTS2.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 3] = Me.txtHTS3.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 4] = Me.txtHTS4.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 5] = Me.txtHTS5.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 6] = Me.txtHTS6.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 7] = Me.txtHTS7.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 8] = Me.txtHTS8.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 9] = Me.txtHTS9.Value
    rstSCR![HTS 10] = Me.txtHTS10.Value
    rstSCR![Cost] = Me.txtCost.Value
    rstSCR![Assist] = Me.txtAssist.Value
    rstSCR![COO] = Me.txtCOO.Value
    rstSCR![Manufacturer Name] = Me.txtMFGNM.Value
    rstSCR![Manufacturer Address] = Me.txtMFGAD.Value
    rstSCR![HTS Description] = Me.txtHTSDESC.Value
    rstSCR![Vendor] = Me.txtVendor.Value
    rstSCR![SCR ID] = "SCR" & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Date) & rstSCR![AutoNumber]

    rstSCR.Update
    rstSCR.Close

    Set rstSCR = Nothing

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Batch PO SCR Form"

    Forms("Record Search").Controls("btnSavePDF").Visible = True

Else
    MsgBox "Cannot create SCR ID becuase required fields are missing. Please see items highlighted in red!", vbOKOnly, "ERROR - CANNOT CREATE ID!"
End If
```

My issue is that on the last line below is not getting the SQL int auto number to put in the field:

```vb
rstSCR![SCR ID] = "SCR" & "-" & DatePart("yyyy",Date) & rstSCR![AutoNumber]
```

The *SCR-2018* shows in the field SCRID as expected it is just **not** pulling in the int primary key (AutoNumber) from the SQL Server table. 
AutoNumber is a Identity (1,1) field. I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: So there is a field in your SQL Server table named *AutoNumber*? Is it an `IDENTITY(1,1)` field? Please update very last sentence as it does not read clearly. Is this field ignored and SRC and year only shows? Any errors?

Comment: You are correct. The SQL Server table has a column named AutoNumber. It is Identity(1,1) field. the SCR-2018 Works fine as that is populated via the VBA but I need to tag the AutoNumber with it. Example  SCR should equal "SCR-201815578" the 15578 is the actual record number on the SQL table. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, to get auto number and other fields as a result of triggers, code etc., you need to save the record. Also, one strange “quirk” of DAO is that when adding a record, the record pointer moves OFF of the current record (this does NOT occur when using DAO to edit existing).

Regardless, simply force the update, and then re-set the record pointer, and then pull + grab the auto number(s) etc.

This code will work:

```
‘ all of you code goes here
rstRecords.Update
rstRecords.Bookmark = rstRecords.LastModified
lngNext = rstRecords!ID
‘ grab any other values from columns such as those set by triggers etc.

rstRecords.Close
```